# request and response handling in asp.net through JSON

Tags: asp.net, json

We are planning to start a new project in which this request and response scenario involved.
our client system may give request to create an order.If all the conditions are met our server system will generate an order and those details will get stored in our database.
server request is through asp.net JSON. JSON is totally new to me.Can any one suggest links through which i can learn and proceed with my project.

Regards,
Sathya

Comment: To start with what is to be done....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is just an object, or array of objects, or list of objects, or... etc, serialized into a string.

The easiest way to understand it (and to put it in place), is using Json.Net:

http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

It's really easy.

Answer (score 0):

[To understand JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/default.asp)
[JSON and ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/211489/Using-JSON-with-ASP-NET-3-5)
[JSON Objects](http://www.json.org/)
[MSDN Introduction to JSON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx)
[Serialize and Deserialize JSON Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx)
You would get many examples of it on internet.. Above are some which I  used and were very helpful to me..